# move .apk files to Nokia 6303

Tags: live-wallpaper

I have downloaded many Live wall papers on my Samsung Galaxy ACE 5830 Phone .

1) Is there a way to move the these to Nokia 6303 Phone

2) how can i install .APK files on the same Nokia Phone from my PC.

Answer (score 2):

The [Nokia 6303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_6303_classic) is not an Android phone. You can't use the live wallpapers or .apk files from your Glaxy Ace on the 6303 unless you've somehow managed to install Android on it (which, since you did not specifically note that you did, I assume you have not).

Comment: @indeevar: If you find answers to your questions helpful, you can consider [accepting them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/150283), so that others will know that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.. Nokia dosen't run Android, and you can only use a apk file on Android devices..

So you need to buy an android phone...

Sorry...